# Advantage of string.Template over str.format

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-formatting, templating

I was trying string templating and came across [`Template` class](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#string.Template).

I could not figure out the advantage of using this instead of a simple `str.format()`.

For example, both

```
s = "hello {name}"
print(s.format(name="Nick"))
```

and

```
from string import Template
s = Template("hello $name")
print(s.substitute(name="Nick"))
```

seems to do the same thing.

I ran a timeit and `str.format()` seems to be faster.

- `str.format()`: 500000 loops, best of 5: 564 nsec per loop
- `string.Template`: 50000 loops, best of 5: 5.03 usec per loop

Is there any advantage of using `string.Template()` instead of simple `str.format()` then?

Edit: Could template strings be **more secure** or something?

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the link. But I hope someone knows something clear especially about security against execution of random code or something.

Comment: The template functions in the strings library simply predates template strings and has continued to be maintained. It is no safer (in fact - note the warning in [safe_substitute](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#string.Template.safe_substitute) method) and lacks the rich functionality. They *may* be safer with user supplied format strings [link](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#4-template-strings-standard-library) but I would not count on that.